# How to implement sending JSON in CakePHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I have to create web page for testing and I don't know how to implement it's logic (because I don't want to break MVC). It will be created in CakePHP.

Base thing I want to do is, that presenters action will have a parameter (JSON object or JSON string) and based on this parameter, there will be created a testing form inside view. 
After user submits the answer, it will be sent to my PHP algorithm as a parameter(type of JSON object or string). This algorithm will return another JSON object that will be used as parameter for above mentioned presenters action.

I don't know how to implement this logic of sending and receiving JSON in order of not breaking MVC rules. Please explain it to me.

Comment: If you are using CakePHP, then you have already broken all of the concepts on which MVC and MVC-inspired patterns are based.

Comment: so please explain me what should i do then, and how it should be

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is think about your design.

The controller can process your data and return a JSON response, so you'll want to use that. Luckily Cake has this built in. Have a read of the book, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

If you are passing JSON into your controller, you'll want to just pick it up out of the request. You'll be able to find it by debugging the request inside your controller. `debug($this->request)`.

Then you can process the JSON in your controller, do some stuff and return a JSON response.

Comment: And I can return JSON response by requestAction? Or I should do it in some other way?  
Or in other words - how to make a .json request